# Hex to RGB conversion using farbtastic color picker

Tags: hex, rgb, farbtastic

I found on two posts on here, 1 on using the *farbtastic colorpicker*, and another on converting *hex to RGB values*. I'm trying to return the RGB values but I'm stuck.

It's returning the object from the color picker when I use:

```
console.log(hex +" in")
```

But after that I can't get any of the conversion part to work?

Help would deeply appreciated as I've only been learning Javascript for around a month now and have hit a wall after a days worth of research.

My code is below:

```
$('#colorpicker').farbtastic (function hexToRgb(hex) {
console.log(hex +" in")
var bigint = parseInt(hex, 16);
var r = (bigint >> 16) & 255;
var g = (bigint >> 8) & 255;
var b = bigint & 255;

return r + "," + g + "," + b;
console.log(hexToRgb +" out")

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out.

> ```
> $('#colorpicker').farbtastic(function(hex){
> $.throttle(250, true, LevelSliderValueChanged)
> redpick = hexToRgb(hex).r;
> greenpick = hexToRgb(hex).g;
> bluepick = hexToRgb(hex).b;
> console.log(hexToRgb(hex).r + " R")
> console.log(hexToRgb(hex).g + " G")
> console.log(hexToRgb(hex).b + " B")
> Updatepick()   })
>
> function hexToRgb(hex) {
> console.log(hex +" in")
> var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
> console.log(result +" split")
>
> return result ? {
>   r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
>   g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
>   b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
> } : null;
> ```
>
> } });